# Javascript ternary operator with two true (?) conditional operators

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operators, ternary-operator

Can somebody help to substitute ? by THEN in the code below please?

```
return e = this.checked ? i - n > 0 ? 0 : i - n < 10 ? 10 : i - n : i - n < 0 ? 10 : i - n > 10 ? 0 : 10 + i - n
```

I am especially confused by ? followed by another ? at the start of the statement `return e = this.checked ? i - n > 0 ? 0 .....`. What does that mean?

Thanks

Comment: Nested ternaries are unreadable

Comment: It is not as hard to read, you only have to follow this: if condition ? when true : when false. and in false statement add another condition is a structure like if(){}else{if(){}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting parentheses and indentation, your code is equivalent to:

```
return e = this.checked
? (
  i - n > 0
  ? 0
  : (
    i - n < 10
    ? 10
    : i - n
  )
)
: (
  i - n < 0
  ? 10
  : (
    i - n > 10
    ? 0
    : 10 + i - n
  )
);
```

In short, inside the first expression or the second expression, you're allowed to nest further ternary operators, because they resolve to expressions too - though, that doesn't mean it's a good idea, it's quite unreadable.

Using if-else and [this tool](http://converter.website-dev.eu/):

```
if (this.checked) {
  if (i - n > 0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    if (i - n < 10) {
      return 10
    } else {
      return i - n
    }
  }
} else {
  if (i - n < 0) {
    return 10
  } else {
    if (i - n > 10) {
      return 0
    } else {
      return 10 + i - n
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For make it more readable you can always add parenthesis to your code as

`return e = this.checked ? ( (i - n > 0 )? 0 : (i - n < 10 ? 10 : i - n ) ) 
                           : 
                          ( (i - n < 0) ? 10 : (i - n > 10 ? 0 : 10 + i - n) )`

or divide into separate parts as @Nick Parsons answer.

Comment: Could you please explain why and how this code provides an answer to the question?

Comment: the confusion of `? :` operator can be solved by using parenthesis, so I did that.

Comment: Don't me wrong, your code seems to work but it isn't very readable which causes the need of an **explanation as an edit of the answer**. Questions and its answers should enable people to solve the same or a similar problem **without having to ask the same question (duplicates)**. Could you please explain in detail how you solved *the confusion of `?`*?

Comment: @deHaar, thanks for your comment I'll be more careful with my answer to be more readable and understandable, as you can tell I am new to stackflow.

Answer (score 0):

It might be useful if you break you ternary up into its separate parts. Essentially it has this basic strucutre:

```
condition ? a : b
```

Here, `a` will be executed if the `condition` evaluates to `true`, and `b` will be triggered if it evaluates to `false`.

So, putting brackets around your separate ternary operators can help clear things up.

```
return e = this.checked ? (i - n > 0 ? 0 : (i - n < 10 ? 10 : i - n)) : (i - n < 0 ? 10 : (i - n > 10 ? 0 : 10 + i - n))
```

So here:

- `condition` *is* `this.checked`
- `a` *is* `(i - n > 0 ? 0 : (i - n < 10 ? 10 : i - n))`
- `b` *is* `(i - n < 0 ? 10 : (i - n > 10 ? 0 : 10 + i - n))`

Or, you may find it easier to understand if you convert it into an if-statement like so:

```
if (this.checked) {
  if (i - n > 0) {
    return 0
  } else {
    if (i - n < 10) {
      return 10;
    } else {
      return i - n;
    }
  }
} else {
  if (i - n < 0) {
    return 10;
  } else {
    if (i - n > 10) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return 10 + i - n;
    }
  }
}
```